# while paging in grid view how to count total rows

Tags: asp.net

I am Using a  grid  view  to enable  pageindexchaning and pageindexchanged i just  entered  some values  at 1,2,3,4,5, out of  20  pages  it has some text box values  at the time of adding it is reading values from only one page out of total pagecount..
but i need all the page  rows should be read   i need your help..
at page load  i have written this code..

```
    Dim sname As String = Session("Current_user")

    If (TextBox3.Text <> "") Then
        TextBox3.Text = ""
    End If
    Button1.BackColor = Drawing.Color.White

    Dim con As connect_comp = New connect_comp()
    ocompany = CType(HttpContext.Current.Session("company"), SAPbobsCOM.Company)
    'Dim myConnection As SqlConnection
    'Dim ConfigStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("PayrollConnectionString").ConnectionString
    'myConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigStr)
    'myConnection.Open()

    Dim RS1 As SAPbobsCOM.Recordset
    RS1 = ocompany.GetBusinessObject(SAPbobsCOM.BoObjectTypes.BoRecordset)
    RS1.DoQuery("select t1.U_ItmCde,t1.U_ItmDes,t1.U_ItmNme,t1.U_UOM    from  [@TI_VITHDR] t0 inner join  [@TI_VITLNE] t1 on  t0.Code =t1.Code  where t0.U_Whse='" & sname & "'")


    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim dr As DataRow = Nothing
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("SNO", GetType(String)))
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("ItemName", GetType(String)))
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("ItemCode", GetType(String)))
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Item Description", GetType(String)))
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("UOM", GetType(String)))

    For i As Integer = 1 To RS1.RecordCount
        dr = dt.NewRow()

        dr("SNO") = i
        dr("ItemName") = RS1.Fields.Item("U_ItmDes").Value
        dr("ItemCode") = RS1.Fields.Item("U_ItmCde").Value
        dr("Item Description") = RS1.Fields.Item("U_ItmNme").Value
        dr("UOM") = RS1.Fields.Item("U_UOM").Value
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)
        RS1.MoveNext()
    Next


    ViewState("CurrentTable") = dt
    Gridview1.DataSource = dt
    Gridview1.DataBind()

-------------------------
page index and page index changed i have written 
Protected Sub Gridview1_PageIndexChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As    GridViewPageEventArgs)
    'Session("Test") = Gridview1
    'Gridview1 = Nothing
    'Gridview1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    'SetInitialRow()
    Response.Write(Gridview1.PageIndex.ToString())
    Dim d As Integer = Gridview1.PageCount
    Dim texts As String() = New String(Gridview1.PageSize - 1) {}
    Dim texts1 As String() = New String(Gridview1.PageSize - 1) {}
    Dim textBox, textBox1 As TextBox
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    For Each row As GridViewRow In Gridview1.Rows
        textBox = DirectCast(row.FindControl("TextBox1"), TextBox)
        textBox1 = DirectCast(row.FindControl("TextBox2"), TextBox)
        If textBox IsNot Nothing Then
            texts(count) = textBox.Text
        Else
            texts(count) = ""
        End If


        If textBox1 IsNot Nothing Then
            texts1(count) = textBox1.Text
        Else
            texts1(count) = ""
        End If
        count += 1

    Next
    Session("page" + Gridview1.PageIndex.ToString()) = texts
    Session("page1" + Gridview1.PageIndex.ToString()) = texts1
    Gridview1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    SetInitialRow()
End Sub
Protected Sub GridView1_PageIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If Session("page" + Gridview1.PageIndex.ToString) IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim textBox As TextBox
        Dim texts As String() = DirectCast(Session("page" + Gridview1.PageIndex.ToString()), String())
        For i As Integer = 0 To Gridview1.Rows.Count - 1
            textBox = DirectCast(Gridview1.Rows(i).FindControl("TextBox1"), TextBox)
            textBox.Text = texts(i)
        Next
    End If

    If Session("page1" + Gridview1.PageIndex.ToString) IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim textBox1 As TextBox
        Dim texts1 As String() = DirectCast(Session("page1" + Gridview1.PageIndex.ToString()), String())
        For i As Integer = 0 To Gridview1.Rows.Count - 1
            textBox1 = DirectCast(Gridview1.Rows(i).FindControl("TextBox2"), TextBox)
            textBox1.Text = texts1(i)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
----------
```

while adding i am counting
     Try
            Dim Cnt1, Rowcnt1 As Integer
            Rowcnt1 = Gridview1.Rows.Count
            For Cnt1 = 0 To Rowcnt1 - 1

here i get the problem it is reading only one page values i need entire  grid rows .
 can any body plz give me some suggestion..

Answer (score 0):

As you are using SQL and querying a database you total number of rows =

```
select Count(*) from  [@TI_VITHDR] t0 inner join  [@TI_VITLNE] t1 on  t0.Code =t1.Code  where t0.U_Whse='" & sname & "'"
```